# Send message automatically bot python

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot

I try to do a simple bot, which can notify a user two times a day at the specified time, using `telebot` library.

```py
import telebot
    
bot = telebot.TeleBot('MY_URL')
    
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def repeat (message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.text)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Now I have a bot, which can repeat all entered messages. And I have some questions.

1. Is it possible to send messages without a `@bot.message_handler`? ( I was trying to do it without `handler` and it is nothing. I guess, I need to use `handler`.)
2. How should I go, if I just want to notify a user twice a day? (I guess, I need `timeout` or something else?)

I was looking for examples, but can't find ones with `telebot`? Can you suggest something?

Comment: I suggest you add a telebot tag to your post. Perhaps it will draw attention from folks using that library.

Comment: Regarding number 2, I have (had) a bot that sent an automated message every morning, ran it with cronjob and a specified hour, you can easily modify yours to send messages twice a day. You just need to know the person's telegram id (I didn't use `telebot` library so you'll need to check how to get the person's `chat_id` from their API, should be fairly easy). [Link](https://github.com/evyatarmeged/telegram-bot) to my library just in case (it's under `autobot.py`)

Comment: @EvyatarMeged    thank you, yes that is what I needed. But can I ask, where the params of sending in your code? Sorry, just can't see where you put the specified time.

Comment: The script is independent and is ran by the operating system on a schedule decided by you. If you're using a Unix-like machine, read about [Cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron), otherwise, look for its windows equivalent.

Comment: @EvyatarMeged   Thank you for helping!